# Maximum area of majority vote of equally-sized circles

Tags: geometry, optimization

Consider $n$ circles of area 1 placed arbitrarily in the plane. Let's define the *majority vote* of these circles as the set of points $V$ which are contained in at least $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ circles.

1. Can the area of $V$ be larger than $1$ when $n = 3$?
2. Can the area of $V$ be larger than $1$ for some $n > 3$?
3. What is the maximum possible area of $V$ for a given $n$?

The question is motivated by the statistical theory of Boosting. (1) is brought up by Patrick Winston in the following lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHBmv7qCey4, (2) and (3) are my extensions. I would be interested in any approximations, asymptotics, or papers regarding this and related questions.

Comment: Can't all the circles coincide, leading to $V$ having the area of a unit circle?

Comment: @angryavian But they are not unit circles. They are circles of area $1$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, if they coincide they have an area of 1 - the question is whether you can get a strictly larger area

Comment: Whoops, misunderstood your question. Nickgard's comment is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the statement as "unit circle," apologies.